# Creating a CALayer with unit vector coordinate system

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calayer, quartz-graphics

I would like to create a CALayer that manages it's sublayers' position using unit vectors. This would allow the base layer to be resized while keeping all of it's sublayers in the same relative position.

Dose this have to be done manually or is there a way to change the coordinate system of a CALayer to achieve this?

I am trying to implement an easy way to handle window resizing. By using unit vectors, all of the sublayers will remain in the same relative positions as the main layer is resized.

Comment: Can you give the context? of what you want to do this?

Comment: Added the context, it's about window resizing

Comment: What do you mean by "using unit vectors"? A point is just a vector with {1,0} and {0,1} being i and j unit vectors.

Comment: A layer where the position (1,1) is always the top right corner, regardless of the size of the base layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac OSX `CALayers` have the `layoutManager` property which allows to set one's own layout engine, unfortunately it's not available on iOS so you have two options:

1. Roll in your own subclass of `CALayer` that will reimplement the `layoutSublayers` method.
2. Implement `layoutSublayersOfLayer:` method in a class and then set an instance of this class as your `CALayer`'s `delegate`.